# How to get the most recent row in a temporal tables history

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.mytable FOR system_time BETWEEN @rowEffFrom AND @rowEffTo t
WHERE    t.anothertableid = 1
ORDER BY t.rowefffrom
```

My table has the following columns relevant to this question:

```
Id, AnotherTableId (FK), Description, RowEffFrom, RowEffTo
```

What I have done is get an entry from tblAnotherTable's history matching certain criteria. I then set @rowEffFrom and @rowEffTo as the RowEffFrom and RowEffTo for the retrieved row (top 1).

myTable has a many to one relationship with tblAnotherTable.

I want to retrieve the latest version of all entries between the @rowEffFrom and @rowEffTo, but one per Id.

e.g.

if my query above returns 2 rows, both with Id of 11, then I just want the most recent. If it returns 6 rows with ids 11,12,13 I want 3 rows with the latest of each version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (  SELECT   Row_number() OVER (partition BY id ORDER BY rowefffrom DESC) rownumber,
                   *
          FROM     dbo.mytable FOR system_time BETWEEN @rowEffFrom AND @rowEffTo t
          WHERE    t.anothertableid = 1 ) mt
WHERE  mt.rownumber = 1
```